# JavaScript Regex Special Cases

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking for help on a regex for JS and adding a few more characters. This is what it currently includes (I think):

- All alphanumeric characters
- space
- apostrophe
- period (dot)
- comma
- underscores and hyphens

My current regex here:

```
/^[\w-\.-\,\s-']+$/
```

Can it be formatted better? This is for a `<input>` text field on a web form, and I'm open to additional suggestions or potential downfalls on my current statement.

Finally, how would I additionally include `$` and `&` and `%` characters?

The JS that checks against my regex is this:

```
function has_error(el, type) {

    var textReg = /^[\w-\.-\,\s-']+$/;

    if ( el.val() == '' || (type=='text' && !textReg.test(el.val())) ) {
        // apply error logic
        return true;
    } else {
        // clear error logic
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful, a dash within a character class denotes a *range*, which you don't want here. Place the dash at the start or end to avoid this. Also, no need to escape the punctuation marks:

```
/^[\w.,'\s-]+$/
```

Adding more characters is easy:

```
/^[\w.,'\s$%&-]+$/
```

Note that `$` means a literal `$` within a character class and not the "end-of-string-anchor".

Comment: Actually, the `'` is not working on iOS. Any ideas to update the regex for iOS Safari?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"? Does it not match the apostrophe? Maybe your text contains typographic apostrophes like `‘’‛′`? Try copying and adding them to your regex.

Comment: My function is preventing form submission with iOS apostrophes. I'll try to add them in.